# Get certain amount of rows after the first 3 php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, joomla2.5

Hi Im trying to get certain amount of rows after the first 3 rows like for example:

this is the rows in the database

-id

- 20
- 19
- 18
- 17
- 16
- 15

When i `select * from #__table where published=1 order by id desc limit 0,3`

i get

20
19
18

as result.

Now what i want to do is create a query where i can get the next ones after the first 3 rows

17
16
15

Comment: You are already using the `limit`/`offset` syntax.  The answer should be obvious:  `limit 3, 3`.

Comment: omg i can believe i forgot about the offset syntax my bad thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to increase your limit with 3

```
SELECT *
FROM #__TABLE
WHERE published=1
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3

Then LIMIT 3,3
Next LIMIT 6,3
```

Comment: yea  gordon made me realize im already using the syntax offset witch i completely forgot. thansk for the help guys